# parse url - javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I try to parse an URL in angular this way:

```
var l = document.createElement("a");
l.href='www.example.com';
console.log(l.hostname); // -> '127.0.0.1'
```

But the log gives me the localhost. Any ideas why that's the case or better ways how to do it?

Comment: protocol is missing in the href so falls back to parent document host.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an absolute url with protocol:

```
l.href='http://www.example.com';
```